# Selecting data from 2 specific dates gives "Division by zero" error

Tags: postgresql

I want to return data from yesterday and 8 days ago.

To do this I use the following line in my query:

```
WHERE (o.status_date::date = now()::date - INTERVAL '8 days') 
OR (o.status_date::date = now()::date - INTERVAL '1 day')
```

However, this returns a "Division by zero" error. When I use only one of the two, so for example:

```
WHERE (o.status_date::date = now()::date - INTERVAL '8 days')
```

I get no error...

I don't understand where the error comes from, or perhaps I'm making a very straightforward mistake. Any help is appreciated!

Edited, these are the calculations done in my query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS failed_63,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('6','11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_orders,
ROUND(
  (SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100)::numeric /
  (SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), 2) AS perc_fail,
COUNT(DISTINCT i.order_id) AS order_issues,
ROUND(
  (COUNT(DISTINCT i.order_id) * 100)::numeric / (SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), 2) AS issue_rate,
SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS overdue_53,
ROUND(
  (SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100)::numeric /
  (SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('6','11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)), 2) AS perc_overdue,
ROUND(
  (AVG(dop.vendor_confirmation_time)::numeric / 60), 2) AS avg_v_confirmation_time,
CASE
  WHEN (AVG(dop.vendor_confirmation_time)::numeric / 60) < 3 THEN 'good'
  WHEN (AVG(dop.vendor_confirmation_time)::numeric / 60) IS NULL THEN 'n/a'
  ELSE 'bad'
END AS vendor_response
```

Comment: It comes from select statement :) post all full query

Comment: @Justin, added the calculations done in the query now :).

Answer (score 0):

You have several cases in your query where your divisor might be 0, as in:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('6','11','12','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The best way to solve this is to use a sub-query to calculate all the sums, which are repeated anyway, and then do the division and rounding in the main query, where the divisor is not 0:

```
SELECT
  sum12 AS failed_63,
  sum6 + sum12 + sum11_24 AS total_orders,
  CASE WHEN sum12 + summ11_24 > 0 THEN round(sum12 * 100. / (sum11_24 + sum 12), 2)
  ELSE NULL END AS perc_fail,
  order_issues,
  CASE WHEN sum12 + summ11_24 > 0 THEN round(order_issues * 100. / (sum12 + sum11_24), 2)
  ELSE NULL END AS issue_rate,
  sum6 AS overdue_53,
  CASE WHEN sum6 + sum12 + sum11_24 > 0 THEN round(sum6 / (sum6 + sum12 + sum11_24), 2)
  ELSE NULL END AS perc_overdue,
  round(avg_v_confirmation_time, 2) AS avg_v_confirmation_time,
  CASE
    WHEN (avg_v_confirmation_time) < 3 THEN 'good'
    WHEN (avg_v_confirmation_time) IS NULL THEN 'n/a'
    ELSE 'bad'
  END AS vendor_response
FROM (
  SELECT
    sum(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum6,
    sum(CASE WHEN o.status_id = '12' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum12,
    sum(CASE WHEN o.status_id IN ('11','14','22','24') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum11_24,
    count(DISTINCT i.order_id) AS order_issues,
    avg(dop.vendor_confirmation_time::numeric / 60) AS avg_v_confirmation_time
  FROM o, i, dop
  WHERE ... ) sub
```

In this case I set all columns where the divisor would be 0 to `NULL`; change as appropriate.

For future questions:

- List your PostgreSQL version
- Post the entire query with table qualifiers for all columns
- Preferably, post the table structure

Comment: Yes, but when I don't get the error if I use one specific date then I should not get the error when using both dates, if I'm correct... It would make sense if there are no orders at all on the date specified because then indeed it would be a division by 0. However, on both dates there are orders so it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The error is a division by 0. Why it is with both dates and not a single date, I can not tell. Post your entire query if you want a better answer. In either case, my answer above avoids any division by 0, whichever the date. Do you perhaps subtract values of separate days from each other?

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the effort to write all that out! I'm new to Postgres so I don't know exactly how to incorporate sub-queries. I'm saving this to implement it as a change later :).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why my first line didn't work, but I've now found a work-around by using the following:

```
WHERE o.status_date::date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '8 days' AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 day'
AND o.status_date::date NOT BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days' AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2 days'
```